# botConnection.activity$ node.js BOT

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, bots

I've deployed a bot written in nodejs using backchannel. In my BOT, I am creating event as follows

creating event in a bot.dialog:

```
    var ev = createEvent('sendUserInfo', "test", session.message.address);
   session.endDialog(ev)
```

event function

```
const createEvent = (eventName, value, address) => {
var msg = new builder.Message().address(address);
msg.data.type = 'event';
msg.data.name = eventName;
msg.data.value = value;
return msg;}
```

In web chat javascript, I am trying to subscribe for this event, but NOT getting any response.

```
  botConnection.activity$
      .filter(activity => activity.type === "event")
      .subscribe(activity => console.log(activity));
```

Same subscription is working properly if I create postActivity from web chat directly.

```
   botConnection
      .postActivity({ type: "event", name: "sendUserInfo", value: "test", from: user })
      .subscribe(id => console.log("success", id));
```

Any suggestion, why I am not able to catch events created from BOT in web chat ?

Other way is working fine, if I create event from web chat and subscribe for event in BOT it working as expected.

```
bot.on("event", function (event) {
    var msg = new builder.Message().address(event.address);
    msg.data.textLocale = "en-us";
    bot.send(msg);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not very clear about your code and scenario. But I send an event in a dialog to web chat, and it is successfully captured in `activity$.filer...`.

In Bot:

```
bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    session.send('You said ' + session.message.text);
    var msg = new builder.Message(session);
    msg.data.type = 'event';
    msg.data.name = 'updateUrl';
    msg.data.value = 'hello world';
    session.send(msg);
});
```

in Web chat:

```
botConnection.activity$
      .filter(activity => {console.log('filter');console.log(activity);return activity.type === "event"})
      .subscribe((activity) => {console.log(activity)});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code but with botConnection altered to what is shown below and it worked just fine. Make the following change and you should be good to go.

Steve.

```
botConnection.activity$
    .filter(function (activity) {
        return activity.type === 'event' && activity.name === 'sendUserInfo';
    })
    .subscribe(function (activity) {
        console.log(activity.name + ' received with value: ' + activity.value);
    });
```